# Are voltdb default procedures partitioned?

Tags: voltdb

`Voltdb` creates set of default procedures on tables with primary keys (like `HELLO_WORLD.insert`, `HELLO_WORLD.upsert`, `HELLO_WORLD.delete` etc).

Are these procedures partitioned if my HELLO_WORLD table is partitioned? .

I couldn't find any documentation on default procedure partitioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the default procedures generated when you create a table in VoltDB are partitioned, if the table is partitioned.

All tables will get an insert procedure.  If the table has a primary key, then upsert, update, and delete procedures are also generated.